# Having problems converting a service made on framework 4.5 to 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, service, downgrade

I created a service that runs fine on framework 4.5. I can install it and run it and everything is great.

However, when I went to deploy on a local server, they are only running Windows 2003, and the framework on it is still 2.0.

I talked to the guy in charge and informed him that I am using a lot of Linq commands and it would be very hard for me to rewrite all of that code, so he agreed to upgrade to 4.0 for me (the latest framework server 2003 can handle).

So I converted all of my projects to target 4.0, ran it in debug mode and the service (running as an application) runs fine.

The service installs fine (installutil.exe servicename.exe) but when I do a "net start" on it, it *immediately* returns "the service is not responding to the control function." I get no other useful information from the event logs.

As I understand it, this usually means that it has taken too long to start up, but the timeout is definitely set to 30000ms and it returns this well under a second. Nothing has changed other than converting the projects to framework 4.0 and I can find no information about "downgrading" from 4.5 to 4.0 and what I might be missing.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: While not the most helpful question...Have you spoken to the guy in charge to see if he's willing to install 4.5?

Comment: I did some research and it appears that the latest version of the framework that will work on server 2003 is 4.0. There may be some hacks to get 4.5 working on it, but I don't want to take up too much of his time.

Comment: @oppassum Not possible, 4.5 only supports Vista or later.

Comment: Oh my apologies I missed that it was Windows 2003.  So it compiles fine, but doesn't run on their computer -- have you looked into possible permissions issues?

Comment: @oppassum I'm doing the testing on my machine first and this is where I can get the service to run after compiling with 4.5 but not with 4.0. So I don't believe it is a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why it wasn't affecting me when it was set to framework 4.5, but some of the dlls were compiling to Win32, and the exe was compiling to x64 so it wouldn't load the dll correctly.

I manually made them all target x86 and the problem went away.